Svelte component in plain HTML
I have a function that returns the HTML code for a custom component. That code, together with more HTML code, is then rendered somewhere else with {@html codeToDisplay}.
My firsts two guesses where:

Return the code for the component as I would write it in a Svelte file and hope for Svelte to do it's magic
Return the code for the component but using the special element svelte:component

I also checked out the Custom element API but it didn't work.
I made a small REPL to see what I did.
So my question is: can Svelte render a custom component from valid HTML code?

(Custom elements should work just fine, it requires a compiler option. If you have a problem with that specifically, create a new question and show everything you did. svelte:component has nothing to do with custom elements.)

Also, why are you even doing this? If you are using {@html} you are in Svelte context, there should not be a reason to not use the component directly.
